# Displaying data from a ContentProvider and a local database in one list on Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

**The problem**

I need to do a T9 contact search for an Android project I'm working on. Now, it would be simple if I just had to pull contacts from the native contacts storage and then do T9 on that, but the problem I have is that I have an additional local database where we store extra content for some contacts in the form of additional numbers that our application displays and handles. I need to do a search based on the contact’s name, number, and the extra numbers (if any) contained in the local database. The local database has IDs that match those of the contacts in the native Android database.
I have been looking for a solution to this problem, and I have gone through these ideas, but none of them seem to be the right solution.

**Try #1**

Write a ContentProvider for our local database, in order to be able to perform a simple join operation between the native Android contacts table and our table, however, it seems that joining tables via ContentProviders is only possible when you write your own ContentProvider, thus making this solution not viable for me, not to mention that Android documentation states that you should not write a ContentProvider if you don’t want to share your data with other applications, which we currently don’t.

**Try #2**

Copy all the needed data from Android’s contacts database into our database, and use ContentObservers to update it constantly. This solution had two major problems: 1) It seemed to have a big overhead, not just on the processor of the device, but also on the development, as we would have to introduce some really delicate update/read/write mechanisms and ensure that our data always stays relatively fresh, while also being performant; 2) A colleague has stated that during contact sync, the ContentObserver fires off events very often, thus making a need for special code to delay the updating, which he says has never really worked out great.

**Try #3**

Use a CursorJoiner to join the two cursors that I have received and then use a MatrixCursor to display all the data, but that solution is not viable since all the data would be kept in memory, and we are working with datasets that have more than 10k rows of data. Even if the memory could handle it, it would be slow to load, which for T9, isn’t really an option. This also pretty much excludes any solution that doesn't use a Cursor to look over data, which is why I am going in that direction.

**Question**

Am I missing something obvious? If I am, please point me in the right way. All of the things that I have tried don’t seem feasible to me, but I’m open to someone modifying them in order to make them worthwhile.

Comment: @usajnf I don't have a problem with writing a `ContentProvider` if it helps solve my particular issue. Right now, we have an utility class that is in charge of all the SQLite work regarding the local database, which works fine. I know that a `ContentProvider` implementation is a nicer abstraction over the data there, but if it doesn't solve this issue, no one is going to approve to write one. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Actually I rethought my last comment because I feel that a Content Provider is really to provide YOUR data to other apps.  As you mentioned in your post, you don't want to do this.  So what type of database is the local data in?

Comment: Just a standard SQLite database. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Does the utility class provide access to the data in that local database?  If so, why do you not like using that approach to get the data?

Comment: Because it would be slow. I need not only to display the data, but also perform a search on it. So, imagine I pull out a `Cursor` with Android's native contacts - there I have most of the data that I need, but I'm missing some crucial info that I also need to perform my search upon. Getting that data row by row would be super slow, and I have no idea how to perform that search without a huge overhead and a waste of memory. That is why I seek a way to get a cursor object with all the data in it already, but read from a database, to avoid the memory overhead of keeping it all in memory.

Comment: Just a small point on android's official documentation on content providers (ie only bother if you want to share with other apps). I don't think it's particularly relevant anymore with tools like syncAdapter and new things coming with Nougat (dataSaver) relying on a contentProvider. Every time I don't use a content provider I end up regretting it down the line.

Comment: @Maslada Thanks for the comment. I had a feeling something like that could be the case. If we opt for `SyncAdapter`s,  I will definitely implement a `ContentResolver`.